# Copy photos from an iPhone to a USB flash drive

Tags: iphone, photos, data-synchronization, photos.app

I can use Photos.app to import photos to my MacBook's internal SSD, but I can't figure out a way to copy them directly to my flash drive.

Is there any way to copy the photos without doing something insane like paying for some closed-source file-copy app or copying one batch at a time to avoid filling up my SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `Image Capture.app`. It is located in your `Applications` folder. From there you can select your iPhone and import the pictures.